# NOSQL Manager for MongoDB throws command failed collection already exists

Tags: mongodb, nosql

While copying collections from one MongoDB server hosted on A to another MongoDB server hosted on B using Copy collection to another database tool of NOSQL Manager we got an error "Command create failed collection already exists code :48"

The option we specified in NOSQL Manager for copy collections is Replace existing collections.

https://www.mongodbmanager.com/clone-mongodb-collection#copy

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have dropCollection privilege on the destination database.